# Declaring a JavaScript object in pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

What's the proper way to declare an object in pseudocode.
For example:

```
const car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
```

Would it be correct to write

object car {
type: "Fiat"
model: "500"
color: "white"
}

Or should a different format be used?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no one "proper" way.  Pseudocode is not a formally defined language that has an accepted syntax.  Rather, it is an informal form of communication.

The criterion is: will it be clear to the reader?  That will require you to use some judgement and knowledge of your audience.

If you are not sure, I suggest you use a different syntax that you are confident readers will understand, and/or include an explanation of your syntax in the text that accompanies the pseudocode.